# Syntax error on print "hello"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just installed 3.4 on a new machine, tried to run something I know works and it failed. I then tried to just type the following into IDLE and it failed:

```
>>> print 'hello'
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print hello
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> print "hello"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

I am confused as to why that would fail.

Comment: You must use parentheses to use the function `print`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Python3.0.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html)

`The print statement has been replaced with a print() function, with keyword arguments to replace most of the special syntax of the old print statement (PEP 3105).`

so try:
`print ("hello")`

Answer (score 1):

I believe with Python 3+ you need parens. Try this:

```
print("Hello")
```

Here is my test:

```
Python 3.3.2 (default, Sep 15 2013, 13:36:01)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print 'hello'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 'hello'
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
>>>
>>> print("Hello")
Hello
>>>
```